# How can I, 'save a search' on my online weather app by using localstorage with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, local-storage, fetch-api

I have finished building an online weather app, using HTML and JS. However, I want to add a save feature, so that users can save and access the names of the cities (and possibly other details) that they have searched for, previously. I have read something on localStorage, but I am not sure how to implement that.

```js
let weather = {
        "apiKey": "",
        fetchWeather: function(city) {
            fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ city + "&units=metric&appid="+ this.apiKey).then((response) => response.json()).then((data)=> this.displayWeather(data));   
             },
             displayWeather: function(data){
                const  {name}= data;
                const {icon, description} = data.weather[0];
                const {temp, humidity} =data.main;
                const {speed} = data.wind;
                console.log(name,icon,description,temp,humidity,speed);
                document.querySelector(".city").innerText = "Weather in " + name;
                document.querySelector(".icon").src = " http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+ icon + ".png";
                document.querySelector(".description").innerText = description;
                document.querySelector(".temp").innerText = temp+ "°C" ;
                document.querySelector(".humidity").innerText = "Humidity " + humidity + "%";
                document.querySelector(".wind").innerText =  "Wind Speed" + speed + "km/h";
             },
             search:function(){
                this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
             }
    } 

    document.querySelector(".search button").addEventListener("click", function() { weather.search(); })

//adding lcoal storage function.

    const history = document.getElementById("historyList");
    const searcher = document.getElementById("searcher");
    const searchCard = document.getElementById("search-card");
    
    let saved = localStorage.getItem("historyList") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("historyList")):[];
    
    searchCard.addEventListener("history", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        saved.push(searcher.value);
        localStorage.setItem("historyList", JSON.stringify(saved));
        listBuilder(searcher.value);
        searcher.value = "";
      });
    
      const listBuilder = (text) => {
        const histories = document.createElement("li");
        histories.innerHTML = text;
        historyList.appendChild(histories);
      };
    
      //function to display history after refreshing
      const getHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("historyList"));
    getHistory.forEach((histories) => {
      listBuilder(histories);
    });
    
    // delete history
    const deleteHistory = (btn) => {
        let el = btn.parentNode;
        const index = [...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el);
        saved.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("histories", JSON.stringify(saved));
        el.remove();
      };
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="card" id="search-card">
         <div class="search">
            <input type="text" name="searchbox" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search...">
            <button></button>
         </div>
         <div class="weather">
            <h2 class="city">Weather in Accra</h2>
            <div class="temp">
               <h1>21°C</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="flex">
               <img src="" alt="" class="icon">
               <div class="description">Cloudy</div>
            </div>
            <div class="humidity">Humid: 53% </div>
            <div class="wind"> Wind Spenter code hereeed: 6.2 km/h</div>
         </div>
         <ul id="historyList"></ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can't search any city because API key is not available.

**EDIT:-** I have added a save a button in HTML and its function in JavaScript but it does not work.

Comment: [Reading the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) would be a useful way to start.

Comment: Its not that hard just read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#examples The exmaples are really really straight forward and easy to understand

Comment: add a save button in your card. After click on save button the city name will save in local storage. Next time user open weather app you have to read city names from local storage and use your weather.search function to add data in your card dynamically.

Comment: did you done with adding save functionality?

Comment: @yashlodi, I am reading the suggested MDN articles to see how I can implement them. I have added the save button to the card.

Comment: @kwameDickson, Ok i will fix and test it  locally. So it takes sometime. Also read this, he  [teach's everything in an interesting way](https://www.codewithharry.com/videos/javascript-tutorials-in-hindi-20/)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained in comments, so it read it first.

```js
// create a weather class to implement weather search, show and extra functionality.
class Weather {
  constructor(apiKey) {
    // set this._apiKey to apiKey to get access of it in overall classl
    this._apiKey = apiKey;
  }

  // arrow function to search weather
  searchWeather = async () => {
    // get search bar value
    const city = searchBar.value;
    // asyncronous fetch request to get weather of a particular city by using city(search bar value) and this._apiKey
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${this._apiKey}`
    );
    // convert response into json object
    const data = await res.json();
    //call and pass data to this.displayWeather function
    this.displayWeather(data, city);
  };

  // arrow function to show current weather
  displayWeather = (data, city) => {
    // extract values from data object and its sub keys by using object destructing
    const { name } = data;
    const { icon, description } = data.weather[0];
    const { temp, humidity } = data.main;
    const { speed } = data.wind;
    // set different values to different elements.
    document.querySelector(".city").innerText = `Weather in ${name}`;
    document.querySelector(
      ".icon"
    ).src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png`;
    document.querySelector(".description").innerText = description;
    document.querySelector(".temp h2").innerText = `${temp}°C`;
    document.querySelector(".humidity").innerText = `Humidity ${humidity}%`;
    document.querySelector(".wind").innerText = `Wind Speed ${speed}km/h`;
    // push search bar value in saved
    saved.push(city);
    // set localStorage historyList item with saved
    localStorage.setItem("historyList", JSON.stringify(saved));
    // call listBuilder function and pass search bar value as a argument
    listBuilder(city);
    // set search bar value to ""(empty string)
    searchBar.value = "";
  };
}

// mian control variable
const controller = new Weather("d3cd4481a1db4ef3b3f161032220103");

const searchBar = document.querySelector(".search-bar");
// get search btn by using querySelector
const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search button");
// add click event on searchBar
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // remove start and end white spaces from search bar value
  const searchBarValue = searchBar.value.trim();
  // if search bar value equals to "" then set result to true else false
  const result = searchBarValue === "";
  // if result equals to true then alert user else search weather
  if (result) {
    alert("Please enter a valid city name.");
  } else {
    controller.searchWeather();
  }
});

//adding local storage function
const history = document.getElementById("historyList"),
  delHistory = document.getElementById("del-history");

// if localStorage has historyList then return it else and empty array
let saved = localStorage.getItem("historyList")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("historyList"))
  : [];

// arrow function to history of searched cities.
const listBuilder = (text) => {
  // create li element
  const histories = document.createElement("li");
  // set li innerText to text
  histories.innerText = text;
  // append histories into historyList
  history.appendChild(histories);
};

//function to display history after refreshing
saved.forEach((histories) => {
  listBuilder(histories);
});

// add click event on delHistory
delHistory.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // remove ul first li
  history.firstElementChild.remove();
  // remove 0 element from saved
  saved.splice(0, 1);
  // set localStorage historyList item with saved
  localStorage.setItem("historyList", JSON.stringify(saved));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Stack Over Flow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stackOverFlow.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card" id="search-card">
      <div class="search">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="searchbox"
          class="search-bar"
          id="search-bar"
          placeholder="Search..."
        />
        <button></button>
      </div>
      <div class="weather" id="weather">
        <h1 class="city">Weather in New Delhi</h1>
        <div class="temp">
          <h2>21°C</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="" alt="" class="icon" />
          <div class="description">Nice</div>
        </div>
        <div class="humidity">Humid: 53%</div>
        <div class="wind">Wind Spenter code hereeed: 6.2 km/h</div>
      </div>
      <ul id="historyList"></ul>
      <button class="del-history" id="del-history">Delete History</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I have done this so far and now its your turn make things better.

---

What you can add also:-

- multiple city weather display at a time using local storage.

I am not sure that this will work 100%.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @yashlodhi. This works, but the list does not display. Just bullets with no content values. 
Also, thanks for the article you suggested, it has helped my understanding of the use of localStorage.

Comment: @kwameDickson i add search bar validation and fix li with no value bug. try that everything works fine now.

Comment: do you mean I should add validation to the search bar, and fix the "li"  by removing values? I am unable to get it. I tried a couple of things but the problem persists.

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything because I updated the code with Validation and li fix. Just try out edited code. That's all !

Comment: Oh okay, I will try that now.